# PowerShell - Copy files to all folders matching a certain pattern

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy certain files to all folders in a directory that end with .com. For example, lets say my file structure was like this:

```
Folder: SourceDirectory
    File: FileToDeploy.txt
    Folder: Server1.com
    Folder: Server2.com
```

The file structure after the PowerShell script runs should look like this:

```
Folder: SourceDirectory
   File: FileToDeploy.txt
   Folder: Server1.com
      File:FileToDeploy.txt
   Folder: Server2.com
      File:FileToDeploy.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. What have you tried so far? Please show your code and explain what or why it didn't work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can discover all immediate subfolders matching the naming pattern with the `-Filter` parameter with `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$file = Get-Item .\path\to\SourceDirectory\FileToDeploy.txt

Get-ChildItem -Path .\path\to\SourceDirectory -Directory -Filter *.com | ForEach-Object {
    $file |Copy-Item -Destination $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per requirements, you can either store the path of file in a variable or directly use the filepath in second line of the code itself. Adjust the paths to fit your requirements. The following code works for you :)

```
$FileToMovePath = 'C:\FileToDeploy.txt'
Get-ChildItem C:\PathToMainDirectory\*.com | ForEach-Object {Copy $FileToMovePath $_.FullName}
```